# Multi Processing while loading data in chunks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to load huge amount of data from one server to SQL Server using the below code. The below code is taking 5-6 hours to load the data. I am trying to implement multi processing in this but i am not able to understand as to how it can be done. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Code

```
src_tbl='src_tbl'
src_qry='select * from x.y'
sn_conn = Conn


sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=server;' 'Database=db;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('Driver={SQL Server};' 'Server=server;' 'Database=db;' 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

tgt_tbl='temp'
now=datetime.datetime.now()

rightNow=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("Data load started.."+str(rightNow))

for chunk in pd.read_sql(src_qry, sn_conn, chunksize=1000000):
    chunk.to_sql(tgt_tbl, con=engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=400 , 
                  method='multi')
```

Comment: ` but i am not able to understand as to how it can be done` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to move a ton of data, you're likely disk I/O bound, not CPU-bound. If that's the case, multithreading likely won't help much at all, but would open you up to the whole host of issues surrounding multithreaded processing.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.